# NavigationDrawer right to left menu items not inflated correctly on api 17

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, menuitem, right-to-left

When I create the default Activity that includes NavigationDrawer in Android Studio I get the following view on RtL phone 
[No item is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zkFh.png).

The items won't be aligned to the right. But when I click on any item I get the following view 
[After any item is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc3TV.png).

Where the items get aligned to the right as long as there count doesn't exceed 5. If more items are included they will not be updated.

The application supports Rtl by default.